# Serialization.read() is not "found" inside a map block [Scala]

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I'm using `json4s` for dealing with Json responses from http responses. I was earlier using `Await` but I'm now switching to use `Future`.

I have a function like:

```
executeRequest(): Future[Response[String]]
```

and another function like:

```
def getAccessToken() = {
 executeRequest().map {
    response: Response[String] => // read method in the next line cannot be resolved
      read[AccessTokenResponse](response.body).access_token
   }
 // the following line is ok
 read[AccessTokenResponse]("{\"access_token\":\"fake_token\"}").access_token
}
```

Now, the `read` inside the `map` block is no longer recognized/found by my IntelliJ which I'm assuming means I'm doing something wrong. But the `read` outside of the `map` block resolves correctly.

What am I doing incorrectly here? I'm new to Scala :/

Compiler output:

```
overloaded method value read with alternatives:
  (in: java.io.Reader)(implicit formats: org.json4s.Formats, implicit mf: scala.reflect.Manifest[AccessTokenResponse])AccessTokenResponse <and>
  (json: org.json4s.JsonInput)(implicit formats: org.json4s.Formats, implicit mf: scala.reflect.Manifest[AccessTokenResponse])AccessTokenResponse <and>
  (json: String)(implicit formats: org.json4s.Formats, implicit mf: scala.reflect.Manifest[AccessTokenResponse])AccessTokenResponse
 cannot be applied to (Either[String,String])
      read[AccessTokenResponse](response.body).access_token
```

Comment: @jwvh added error from compiler

Comment: BEWARE: Json4s is [vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error which you are getting means that the `read` method can accept an argument of one of these types:

- `java.io.Reader`
- `org.json4s.JsonInput`
- `String`

This line works because you are passing a `String` to `read`:

```
read[AccessTokenResponse]("{\"access_token\":\"fake_token\"}").access_token
```

However, as we can see from the error message, the `response.body` type is `Either[String,String]`.

[`Either`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Either.html) is a sum type with two variants: `Left` and `Right`. Basically, that means that when a method returns `Either[A, B]`, the actual result can be **either** `A` **or** `B` wrapped into `Left` or `Right` respectively.

`Either` is often used to represent a result of an operation which can fail, where `Left` is returned in case of an error while `Right` contains the result of the operation in case of success. If this is the case, you might want to pattern match on the result to extract the value:

```
executeRequest().map { response =>
  response.body match {
    case Right(body) =>
      read[AccessTokenResponse](body).access_token
    case Left(err) =>
      // Handle the error here
  }
}
```